# Best way to kill monsters at low research in Don't Starve?

Tags: dont-starve

Bought Don't Starve the other day, really enjoying it.  However, I keep dying to mobs like the spiders and spider nests.  I'm attacking with the beginning tools like the axe and pick but it takes quite a few hits to deal with them.  Is there a certain research that will give me an item to kill monsters faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the spear very early on, and make it with easily obtained materials. You can kill spiders in two hits with it, and it loses durability very slowly. Research it at a science machine.

Comment: Thanks, totally missed the spear.  Figured weapons were under the same category as the axe and such.  I kept seeing log suit in the weapons section and thought that meant it was just for armor.